# iphone UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, nsarray, label, uiactionsheet

I have used two different NSArray to display data in two different labels in a custom TABLE VIEW. How can I delete a cell from the table view using UIActionSheet (using UIActionSheet's destructive button) such that the data also gets deleted from the NSArray?

Comment: delete the selected item from the nsarray and reload the table

Comment: [array removeObjectAtIndex:specPosition]; and then reload table [tableView reloadData];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remove it from arrray 
[arrayName removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

And then reload the table:

[table reloadData];

Comment: Note that your arrays need to be NSMutableArrays